# How to export nested Data Table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, export-to-excel, nested-table

I am working with jQuery DataTables. Below is the code for it. I know how to export the DataTable, but how can I export a nested child table in a row? I am not sure how to achieve this. Is there a way to do this using jQuery DataTables or Is there any other library that is easy to use?

I am ok to use any other library if DataTables doesn't support the child tables?

```js
function divexpandcollapse(courseSessionid) {
  if (
    $("#lnkCourseSessionDetails" + courseSessionid)
    .html()
    .trim() === "Expand +"
  ) {
    $("#lnkCourseSessionDetails" + courseSessionid)
      .closest("tr")
      .addClass("left-bordered-3 right-bordered-3 top-bordered-3");
    $("#lnkCourseSessionDetails" + courseSessionid)
      .closest("tr")
      .after(
        "<tr class='left-bordered-3 right-bordered-3 bottom-bordered-3 subtableRow'><div><td  colspan = '100%'>" +
        $("#lnkCourseSessionDetails" + courseSessionid)
        .next()
        .html() +
        "</td></div></tr>"
      );
    $("#lnkCourseSessionDetails" + courseSessionid).html(" Collapse - ");
  } else if (
    $("#lnkCourseSessionDetails" + courseSessionid)
    .html()
    .trim() === "Collapse -"
  ) {
    $("#lnkCourseSessionDetails" + courseSessionid)
      .closest("tr")
      .removeClass("left-bordered-3 right-bordered-3 top-bordered-3");
    $("#lnkCourseSessionDetails" + courseSessionid)
      .closest("tr")
      .next()
      .remove();
    $("#lnkCourseSessionDetails" + courseSessionid).html(" Expand + ");
  } else if (
    $("#lnkCourseSessionDetails" + courseSessionid)
    .html()
    .trim() === "Afficher +"
  ) {
    $("#lnkCourseSessionDetails" + courseSessionid)
      .closest("tr")
      .addClass("left-bordered-3 right-bordered-3 top-bordered-3");
    $("#lnkCourseSessionDetails" + courseSessionid)
      .closest("tr")
      .after(
        "<tr class='left-bordered-3 right-bordered-3 bottom-bordered-3 subtableRow'><div><td colspan = '100%'>" +
        $("#lnkCourseSessionDetails" + courseSessionid)
        .next()
        .html() +
        "</td></div></tr>"
      );
    $("#lnkCourseSessionDetails" + courseSessionid).html(" Cacher - ");
  } else if (
    $("#lnkCourseSessionDetails" + courseSessionid)
    .html()
    .trim() === "Cacher -"
  ) {
    $("#lnkCourseSessionDetails" + courseSessionid)
      .closest("tr")
      .removeClass("left-bordered-3 right-bordered-3 top-bordered-3");
    $("#lnkCourseSessionDetails" + courseSessionid)
      .closest("tr")
      .next()
      .remove();
    $("#lnkCourseSessionDetails" + courseSessionid).html(" Afficher + ");
  }

  $("td:has(>div:has(>table.subtable))").css("padding-left", "0");
}

$('#ContentContainer_MainContent_gvTransaction').DataTable({
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [
    "excelHtml5"
  ]
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <table id="ContentContainer_MainContent_gvTransaction">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 145px;">Order Details</th>
        <th scope="col" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 101px;">Date</th>
        <th scope="col" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 157px;">Order Amount</th>
        <th scope="col" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 169px;">Purchase Order</th>
        <th scope="col" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 160px;">Order Number</th>
        <th scope="col" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 195px;">Transaction Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr class="left-bordered-3 right-bordered-3 top-bordered-3 odd">
        <td class="EntireRow">
          <a id="lnkCourseSessionDetails5cef3869-d01c-ed11-b83e-000d3af4e40a" class="lnkOrderDetails" href="JavaScript:divexpandcollapse('5cef3869-d01c-ed11-b83e-000d3af4e40a');"> Expand + </a>
          <div id="ContentContainer_MainContent_gvTransaction_pnlOrders_0" style="display: none">
            <div>
              <table class="table table-responsive subtable" cellspacing="0" id="ContentContainer_MainContent_gvTransaction_gvCoursePaymentTransaction_0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
                    <th scope="col">Course Number</th>
                    <th scope="col">End Date</th>
                    <th scope="col">TP Reference Number</th>
                    <th scope="col">Participants</th>
                    <th scope="col">Submitted</th>
                    <th scope="col">Course Cost</th>
                    <th scope="col">Subtotal</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="hidden-xs"><input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentContainer$MainContent$gvTransaction$ctl02$gvCoursePaymentTransaction$ctl02$IDVal" id="ContentContainer_MainContent_gvTransaction_gvCoursePaymentTransaction_0_IDVal_0" value="9d1357ec-8283-ec11-8d20-0022486dddc2"></td>
                    <td><a href="../CourseManagement/SessionParticipantsandInstructors/?id=ee8d0589-0df6-eb11-94ef-000d3a09e7f6" target="_blank">1287207</a></td>
                    <td>2021-08-18</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>2</td>

                    <td>No</td>

                    <td>$10.00</td>
                    <td>$20.00</td>
                  </tr>

                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>

          </div>
        </td>
        <td class=" BackgroundGray">2022-08-15</td>
        <td>$20.00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Cancelled</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As DataTables doesn't support child export, I have to create a  hidden table with all the rows and export that instead of the table shown in the view.